# useEffect not triggering when clicking on dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I got a button that triggers data fetching from `fetchDataHandler`, that works with `useEffect`, it fetch data on page load also. But then when I add `addMovieHandler` as dependency to `useEffect` to auto-fetch data when I add another movie, it just doesn't work. So I figured out I may be using it wrong, but cant figure it out.

```
const App = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchDataHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const respone = await fetch(
      "https://react-http-3af47-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/movies.json"
    );
    if (!respone.ok) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
    }
    const data = await respone.json();
    const movieList = [];

    for (const key in data) {
      movieList.push({
        id: key,
        title: data[key].title,
        text: data[key].text,
      });
    }

    setMovies(movieList);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  const addMovieHandler = useCallback(async (movie) => {
    const respone = await fetch(
      "https://react-http-3af47-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/movies.json",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(movie),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await respone.json();
    console.log(data);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataHandler();
  }, [fetchDataHandler, addMovieHandler]);

  let content = <p>no movies found</p>;

  if (movies.length > 0) {
    content = <MovieList movies={movies} />;
  }
  if (isLoading) {
    content = <p>loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <UserInput onAddMovie={addMovieHandler}></UserInput>
      <Card>
        <button onClick={fetchDataHandler}>Fetch movies</button>
      </Card>
      {content}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

Remove `addMovieHandler` from `useEffect`. When you hit `addMovieHandler` it is fetching the data anyway. So what you could to is set the movies with the latest response in the handler itself like so:

`setMovies(...data)`

This will replace the movie list with the newly fetched movie list. If you want to add on the old list you could do this:

`setMovies([...movies, data])`

This is concatenate the new fetched list to the already existing movie list and update the variable and re-render the movie list section as well.

Comment: This solution fixes my problem with useEffect, but it renders a empty card. But that is something I need to look into. Thank you for your answer! Helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` is not triggering on `addMovieHandler` reference change because you're using `useCallback` with no dependencies (`[]` second parameter) to memoize it. This means the `addMovieHandler` reference won't change at all between rerenders but you're basing your `useEffect` calls on it doing so. In simple words - `useEffect` won't rerun if the provided dependencies have the same values (which is the case in your solution).

Same goes for `fetchDataHandler`.

In any case, this is not a good solution to the problem. You should be better-off updating your `movies` array on successful movie addition in the `addMovieHandler` itself. Same goes for other operations like delete and update.